# How to bind a default selected row from table in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

In my application, Iam having a table binded by calling Web Api service.

I have written code to display the selected row when a particular row is selected and it works fine.

Now, I want to show a selected row by default once the web api method returned success message.

How should i call 'SelectConfig' inside success method. When I tried it returns nothing. Please help me to get out of these problem.

My HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: datas">
    <tr>
       <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" />
       </td>
       <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
           <a id="aTag" data-bind="text: (Name().length > 20 ? Name().substring(0, 20) + '....' : Name()), value: ID, click: $parent.SelectConfig"></a>
       </td>
       <td style="vertical-align: middle;" data-bind="text: Type == '' || Type == null || Type == undefined ? '--' : Type"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

<div data-bind="with: Selected, visible: isVisibleDetails">
    <div class="col-md-8 value" data-bind="text: (Name() == '' || Name() == null || Name() == undefined) ? '--' : Name">
    <select id="ddlType_E" data-bind="options: $root.ddlTypes, optionsText: 'Type', optionsValue: 'ID', optionsCaption: 'Select..', value: selectedTypeId" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

My View Model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function oppConfig(ID, Name,TypeID) {
        this.ID = ko.observable(ID);
        this.Name = ko.observable(Name);
        this.selectedTypeId = ko.observable(TypeID);
    }
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        this.datas= ko.observableArray([]);
        getdatas();

        this.ddlTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
        getOppType();
    }
    this.Selected = ko.observable(this.datas()[0]);

        //selectItem
        this.SelectConfig = function (oppConfig) {
            alert(ko.toJSON(oppConfig));
            self.Selected(oppConfig);
        }
    function datas() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '---',
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                processData: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    self.datas.destroyAll();
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (index) {
                            self.datas.push(new oppConfig(data[index].ID, data[index].Name,  data[index].Type));
                        });

                  //Here, I want the to call the select config
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: Is it showing any error

Comment: One thing don't initialize the self.selected = ko.observable(this.datas()[0]); Because when the script start executing it might show error because that time there is no data in the datas array

Comment: `this.Selected` should be inside `ViewModel` i believe  and try something like this to access `this.SelectConfig ` demo fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/25/ cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the data-binding to the `<tr>` element in your HTML markup. Right now, you have the display div for what is selected, but not the selected value itself.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.datas">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectThing, css: { selected: isSelected} ">
```

Then in your view model, add a function to return the selected thing:
Also add an observable for the object itself.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.datas= ko.observableArray([0]);
    getdatas();

    this.ddlTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
    getOppType();
    self.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observable();
    self.selectThing = function(item){
        self.model.CurrentSelected = ko.observable();
    }
}
```

Finally, in your object representing your config class, add an isSelected variable, which is a knockout function.

```
function oppConfig(ID, Name,TypeID) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(ID);
    this.Name = ko.observable(Name);
    this.selectedTypeId = ko.observable(TypeID);
    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function(){
        return selected() === self;
    }
}
```

Some CSS to display your selection:

```
.selected { background-color: yellow; }

thead tr {
    border:1px solid black;
    background:lightgray;
}
tbody tr {
    border:1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```